# Loops that continue until all possible answers had been found

Tags: javascript

```
function TotalAwards(fullName){
var medals = getColumn("Olympic Medals", "Medal");
var firstName = getColumn("Olympic Medals", "Athlete First Name");
var lastName = getColumn("Olympic Medals", "Athlete Last Name");
 for(var i=0; i<medals.length; i++){
   if (firstName[i] + " " + lastName[i] == fullName){
     return medals[i];
   }
  }
 return "Not found";
}
```

So this code is to call on the awards won by a particular winner. What's wrong here is that it only gets the first award of the winner. the second , third , fourth awards are not included. Can anyone help me to fix this?

```
console.log (TotalAwards(" Mathew Helm", true));
```

when I tried with console log to list down the awards of mathew helm, it only prints out his first medal which is silver. The others awards he received in the later years are'nt printed put

Comment: You will need to store the matched values in an array and return the array.

Comment: Hi Grettaggn, it's because your return the first one and doesn't loop the entirely array, I let an example code below using good practices. Regards!

Comment: Yup I did that and it works, thanks everyone!

Comment: That's great!!! Any doubt here we're, keep going! :D. Could be better if you up vote my response, so I could help more people, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function TotalAwards(fullName){
   const medals = getColumn("Olympic Medals", "Medal");
   const firstName = getColumn("Olympic Medals", "Athlete First Name");
   const lastName = getColumn("Olympic Medals", "Athlete Last Name");

   let result = []

   medals?.map((medal, index) => {
     firstName[index] + " " + lastName[index] == fullName && result.push(medal)
   })

  if (result.length === 0) {
    return "Not found";
  }

  return result;
}
```

I Think it works properly, it's better use `const` instead of `var` and `let` when the variable value could change its value during the progress. The conditional operator '?' check that medals exists, otherwise won't loop.

Answer (score 4):

You are only getting the first award of the winner because you call `return` if the first condition is met. The solution is to add the values to an array and return the result.

```
function totalAwards(fullName) {
  var medals = getColumn("Olympic Medals", "Medal");
  var firstName = getColumn("Olympic Medals", "Athlete First Name");
  var lastName = getColumn("Olympic Medals", "Athlete Last Name");
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < medals.length; i++) {
    if (firstName[i] + " " + lastName[i] === fullName) {
      result.push(medals[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

One alternative to the for loop is the filter function. You can read more about it  [in the mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). It would be something like this:

```
function totalAwards(fullName) {
   const medals = getColumn("Olympic Medals", "Medal");
   const firstName = getColumn("Olympic Medals", "Athlete First Name");
   const lastName = getColumn("Olympic Medals", "Athlete Last Name");
   return medals.filter((medal, index) => {
     return firstName[index] + " " + lastName[index] === fullName
   })
}
```

I'm using the `const` variable declaration because `const` and `let` are the recommended way of declaring variables in JavaScript. [This JavaScript Info chapter explains it very well](https://javascript.info/variables) and [in this one they go deep into the differences](https://javascript.info/var).

Comment: Hi Dude, your response is almost the same than mine, unless up vote mine below! Regards!

Comment: @Manuel. You do know that two developers can arrive at similar answers, right?

Comment: @Andy Of course mate, but if there's something too similar even the text, it's better let a comment below if you want to add something else or unless up vote :)

Comment: Your example doesn't have a closing `}` and is poorly formatted. @Manuel

Comment: @Andy Of course, because I don't used any ide or text editor, just copied the original code and fix the important thing. Never mind mate, you don't catch what I meant, Good luck!

Comment: I understood what you meant I just don't agree with it. Based on a question where code has been provided two developers can arrive at similar conclusions. JS is a finite language after all. But if you're going to post answers here at least make sure you put your best effort in and make sure the examples you give a) are formatted properly b) work.

Comment: @Andy Thanks by your suggestions Andy, I've formatted the code and added the missing bracket ' } '.

 I think it's enough replies in this thread. See you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238991/discussion-between-manuel-and-andy).

Answer (score 3):

This is because you exit the loop on first match. What you need is load the results into an array and return it instead:

```
function TotalAwards(fullName) {
  var medals = getColumn("Olympic Medals", "Medal");
  var firstName = getColumn("Olympic Medals", "Athlete First Name");
  var lastName = getColumn("Olympic Medals", "Athlete Last Name");
  let result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < medals.length; i++) {
    if (firstName[i] + " " + lastName[i] == fullName) {
      result.push(medals[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Hello! I've tried putting it in an array and returning it like what you did and it finally works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function TotalAwards(fullName){
  let result = [];
  var medals = getColumn("Olympic Medals", "Medal");
  var firstName = getColumn("Olympic Medals", "Athlete First Name");
  var lastName = getColumn("Olympic Medals", "Athlete Last Name");
  for(var i=0; i<medals.length; i++){
    if (firstName[i] + " " + lastName[i] == fullName){
      result.push(medals[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Like this?